# Any suggestions how it would be good to promote software in a small company ?

Tags: free-software

Ok, I know if I am Red hat or other giant and offer some support etc. I can be profitable, in fact, Red Hat is doing quite well.

However, what about a small company where I create a small program. e.g. an instant messenger for a windows or linux (just as an illustration) and I want to sell it.

But how can I sell it if it is free and everybody can download it?

Any advice?

I like the idea of FSF by Richard Stallman, however I am missing the way how to sell my software under GNU/GPL licence.

Any advice, how can I solve this problem? Any profitable small business software developers around with their opinion?

Any links or names of small companies taht I can look at and study their model of business?

Comment: Do you mean to spread your software for FREE or dell it to make money ?

Comment: By FSF definition of Free software I have to make source code available for the people (the 2nd and 3rd rule) so they can modify the software. But with this I think they will not pay me moeny if they can download the source code and compile it themselves. :( Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, there is a way with Trail version.

Comment: THe problem is that I have to make the source code available for everybody http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html.en So, trail, is no option, because everybody can remove the trail code from the source and I do not think that restriction like trail are possible for free software defined by FSF :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to make your `Trial version first` and spread it for FREE.
After your product become solid to be commercial (may take 6-12 months) you release a commercial version where you should support your paid customers.

Selling free software is `logically non-sense`. You may **provide support service for open-source free software** and charge for it, but not sell it.

Look at my post **to a similar question**, that might be the thing you look for - [How to promote my newly developed software](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/154409/57164)

Comment: Hmm, that is sad, but probably true. I thought that, maybe, I can make money and Stallman's ideas can be transfered into this world where money exist, but it seems that it's only an idea suitable for a society where money are non-existent.

Comment: why sad? it just takes more planning and strategy than just developing a product.

Comment: ;D do not worry, I know . Here we go.

Comment: If you do this, be sure you make it *very* clear that the free version is a trial version, and that the final product will not be free, or that the product is free for home users but not business users, or whatever.  You'll create a lot of ill will if you suddenly change the terms from free to unfree.

Comment: @Derfder **Selling software** is in most cases logical nonsense. In properitary software, what you offer (often but not always in return for payment) is a *license* that allows certain limited use of the software, but you are not *selling* (the rights to) the software itself. If you want to get into making money from software, make sure that you fully understand that distinction, and its implications.

Comment: If selling software is nonsense, you can tell it to Amazon http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=1199154

Comment: @Derfder So if I were to buy a copy of Windows 7 on Amazon, I get full rights to it (including rights to the source code)? No. It's a commonly used expression to "buy" or "sell" software, and in casual conversation it works, but particularly with proprietary software, from a *legal* point of view what you are selling is a *license*, not a *copy*. Generaly speaking, the copy is incidental and only needed so that you can exercise the rights you obtain under the license.

Comment: I do not get what are you trying to say at all. I was asking about a business model, because I am a programmer and I want to sell my software. You started a talk about things like that selling software is not possible because it is illogical nonsense. Say something to the business model or please, do not talk at all. Btw. I flagged your comments as non-constructive.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think most of what I say in [my answer to *"how do I maximize exposure given limited time and no budget"*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150356/ive-released-a-software-product-how-do-i-maximize-exposure-given-no-budget-an/151906#151906) would still be applicable: you basically have a slightly better budget, AND probably at least some time. Some most of the recommendations would apply.

I'm not sure if I should duplicate the content here (seems like a bad idea, especially considering it's a rather large answer), so just follow the [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150356/ive-released-a-software-product-how-do-i-maximize-exposure-given-no-budget-an/151906#151906).